# xcodebuild: find where the output app file is

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

Is there anyway to specify where to put the output file (ie .app) for xcodebuild? By default it is in:

> /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-crkyjjbuqqnqqvfxehsjsarzlbbr/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Project.app

As I need to find the output Project.app file, if there is no way to specify the path, can I use a script to look for that "/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/" folder and inside it find the one with latest modified date and prefix "Project-"? What does the script look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Override the CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR environment variable in an xcodebuild argument. For instance, this command would put its build products under "/tmp/sportsball/":

`xcodebuild -workspace Sportsball.xcworkspace -scheme "Sportsball Debug" -configuration Debug clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/tmp/sportsball/`

Comment: How do you specify a directory relative to project file or $PWD?