# How to make the Xcode build a binary for my project into a consistent location, if I copy my project to another computer?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I am using Xcode 14.1 to build a native macOS app. It outputs the binary into a folder, as such:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-<crazy_string>/Build/Products/<debug-or-release>/ProjectName
```

I build the project using `xcodebuild` and then have my Bash script take the resulting binary from that location.

The issue is that if I hard-code that path relative to my build script, the `<crazy_string>` part of the build folder changes if I move the project to another computer.

Is there a way to know that `<crazy_string>` part that Xcode uses?

Or make Xcode place the resulting binary in a consistent location that doesn't change across computers?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461586/xcodebuild-find-where-the-output-app-file-is

Comment: @matt this is the answer, thanks. Because I don't want to archive anything like that "duplicate" suggests.

Comment: I'll add that one to the list — thank you!